# Filtering out a generator

Tags: python, filter, generator

Whats the best way to filter out some subsets from a generator.  For example I have a string "1023" and want to produce all possible combinations of each of the digits.  All combinations would be:

```
['1', '0', '2', '3']
['1', '0', '23']
['1', '02', '3']
['1', '023']
['10', '2', '3']
['10', '23']
['102', '3']
['1023']
```

I am not interested in a subset that contains a leading 0 on any of the items, so the valid ones are:

```
['1', '0', '2', '3']
['1', '0', '23']
['10', '2', '3']
['10', '23']
['102', '3']
['1023']
```

I have two questions.

1) If using a generator, whats the best way to filter out the ones with leading zeroes.  Currently, I generate all combinations then loop through it afterwards and only continuing if the subset is valid.  For simplicity I am only printing the subset in the sample code.  Assuming the generator that was created is very long or if it constains a lot of invalid subsets, its almost a waste to loop through the entire generator.  Is there a way to stop the generator when it sees an invalid item (one with leading zero) then filter it off 'allCombinations'

2) If the above doesn't exist, whats a better way to generate these combinations (disregarding combinations with leading zeroes).

Code using a generator:

```
import itertools

def isValid(subset):         ## DIGITS WITH LEADING 0 IS NOT VALID
    valid = True
    for num in subset:
        if num[0] == '0' and len(num) > 1:
            valid = False
            break

    return valid

def get_combinations(source, comb):
    res = ""
    for x, action in zip(source, comb + (0,)):
        res += x
        if action == 0:
            yield res
            res = ""

digits = "1023"
allCombinations = [list(get_combinations(digits, c)) for c in itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=len(digits) - 1)]


for subset in allCombinations:   ## LOOPS THROUGH THE ENTIRE GENERATOR
    if isValid(subset):
        print(subset)
```

Comment: Have you seen the `filter` built-in function?

Comment: @aryamccarthy: In Python 2, `filter` is eager, it returns a list, not a generator.

Comment: In Python 2, there's `itertools.ifilter` for lazy evaluation. I don't see a Python 2 tag.

Comment: Was looking for a python 3 solution, but python 2 is ok as well.  How would i integrate 'filter' in my list comprehension of 'allCombinations'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtering for an easy and obvious condition like "no leading zeros", it can be more efficiently done at the combination building level.

```
def generate_pieces(input_string, predicate):
    if input_string:
        if predicate(input_string):
            yield [input_string]
        for item_size in range(1, len(input_string)+1):
            item = input_string[:item_size]
            if not predicate(item):
                continue
            rest = input_string[item_size:]
            for rest_piece in generate_pieces(rest, predicate):
                yield [item] + rest_piece
```

Generating every combination of cuts, so long it's not even funny:

```
>>> list(generate_pieces('10002', lambda x: True))
[['10002'], ['1', '0002'], ['1', '0', '002'], ['1', '0', '0', '02'], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '2'], ['1', '0', '00', '2'], ['1', '00', '02'], ['1', '00', '0', '2'], ['1', '000', '2'], ['10', '002'], ['10', '0', '02'], ['10', '0', '0', '2'], ['10', '00', '2'], ['100', '02'], ['100', '0', '2'], ['1000', '2']]
```

Only those where no fragment has leading zeros:

```
>>> list(generate_pieces('10002', lambda x: not x.startswith('0')))
[['10002'], ['1000', '2']]
```

Substrings that start with a zero were never considered for the recursive step.

Comment: Yes it is more efficient to do the filtering during the building process.  Thanks for the sample code

Comment: A '0' is actually valid.  Only items with leading 0, meaning len is at least 2 or more with leading '0' are invalid.

Comment: `lambda x: x == '0' or not x.startswith('0')` works.

Answer (score 0):

One common solution is to try filtering just before using `yield`.  I have given you an example of filtering just before yield:

```
import itertools

def my_gen(my_string):

    # Create combinations
    for length in range(len(my_string)):
        for my_tuple in itertools.combinations(my_string, length+1):

            # This is the string you would like to output
            output_string = "".join(my_tuple)

            # filter here:
            if output_string[0] != '0':
                yield output_string


my_string = '1023'
print(list(my_gen(my_string)))
```

EDIT: Added in a generator comprehension alternative

```
import itertools

my_string = '1023'
my_gen = ("".join(my_tuple)[0] for length in range(len(my_string))
                      for my_tuple in itertools.combinations(my_string, length+1)
                      if "".join(my_tuple)[0] != '0')
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't give the answer that I want, but I think you are just trying to show me a filter before 'yield'.  I was thinking that but I dont think I can do it since I have a list comprehension of 'allCombinations'.  Would like to stick with list comprehension for speed but maybe I cant

Comment: List comprehensions are fast because they pre-allocate space for the list in C/C++.  I don't believe that generator comprehensions are faster than generator functions strictly because there is no list to fill - items are calculated one at a time.